# Showing non-list updated value from secondary navigation page on primary page using Xamarin.Forms, binding, and MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding

This is my first StackOverflow question! I'm trying to get data bound to a ViewModel to appear on one page, allow it to be changed on another page, then appear in its changed form on the first page.

I have a MainPage displaying a label bound to the property ContactName in the ViewModel ContactViewModel. A button on MainPage pushes the DataEntryPage. On the DataEntryPage I have an entry field also bound to the ContactName. A save button pops the page and returns to MainPage.

I want to enter a new value on DataEntryPage, press save, and have the new value display in the label on the MainPage.

If I initialize ContactName, the value appears both on the MainPage and in the entry field of the DataEntryPage. But when I enter a new value and press save, the old value is displayed on MainPage.

I can make the new value display if I add a static instantiation of the ContactViewModel, explicitly set it to the new value in the DataEntryPage save, then force a refresh by overriding the MainPage's OnAppearing and setting the label to that value. With an ObservableCollection and ListView it's super easy, but I can't make it happen with a single property. It seems like I'm missing some basic ability of MVVC.

The stripped down code is--

```
MainPage.xaml:
<Label Text="{Binding ContactName}">
    <Label.BindingContext>
        <local:ContactViewModel />
    </Label.BindingContext>
</Label>
```

(a Button which triggers code below)
W
MainPage.xaml.cs:
(Button clicked code)

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new DataEntryPage());
```

DataEntryPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ContactViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

(then in a StackLayout)

```
<Entry Text={Binding ContactName} />
```

(Button for save)

DataEntryPage.xaml.cs
(Button clicked code)

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

And finally the ContactViewModel.cs

```
    public class ContactViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        string contactName;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ContactViewModel()
        {                 
            contactName = "OriginalName";
        }

        public static ContactViewModel cvm = new ContactViewModel();     

        public string ContactName
        {
            set {
                if (contactName!=value)
                {
                    contactName = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged!=null )
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ContactName"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return contactName;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Is there a simple solution to this problem? I would prefer to use vanilla Xamarin.forms/C# unless it's absolutely impossible to do without. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the following in XAML

`<Control.BindingContext>
    <local:ContactViewModel/>
<Control.BindingContext>`

a new instance is created. So the `DataEntryPage` is creating its own instance of `ContactViewModel`. So the instance that you are updating on the `DataEntryPage` is different from the instance that you are using to bind the `Text` property of `Label` on the `MainPage`. Using same instance for the pages should resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added the Mode=TwoWay, but the MainPage bound label still doesn't update automatically.

Comment: any input control (like Entry) should default to TwoWay binding

Comment: Thank you @zafar! That make sense. I'm trying that now. Can I ask a further question? Should I declare the instance in the ```ContactViewModel``` or somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you, @zafar! I declared the instance in MainPage and used the xaml.cs to set the BindingContext and that did it! I have upvoted your comment and will check your answer as correct (hopefully both will show up when I get my reputation score high enough).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Jason! I tried to memorize each control/binding type, but you made it much easier to remember.

Comment: @jason yes, you are right `InputView.TextProperty` defaults to `TwoWay`